# pandoc/Markdown: how to remove trailing commas from list template?

Tags: markdown, pandoc, yaml

Suppose I have YAML list (or other supported format) that I want to print as a comma-separated list in a markdown format.

`data.yml`:

```
---
items:
    - item1
    - item2
    - item3
---
```

`template.markdown`:

```
**Items**: $for(items)$$items$, $endfor$
```

How do I get rid of the trailing comma so I get:

```
**Items:** item1, item2, item3
```

Instead of:

```
**Items:** item1, item2, item3,
```

With:

```
pandoc -t markdown --template template.markdown -o output.md data.yml
```

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `$sep$` specifier instead of just hardcoded `,`  in the template.

So:

```
**Items**: $for(items)$$items$$sep$, $endfor$
```

See [`for` loop documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#for-loops).